# How can Karma loads modules by id?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, karma-runner

My project structure is like this:

```
├── src
|   ├── js
|       └── a.js
├── test
|   ├── spec
|        └── test_a.js
```

My `a.js` looks like this:

```
define('A/B/C', function(){
    var D = ...
    return D;
})
```

In my `karma.conf.js`, I have include `requirejs` in `frameworks`, and the needed files are included as follows:

```
files: [
        {pattern: 'src/js/*.js', included: false},
        {pattern: 'test/spec/*.js', included: false},
        'test/test-bootstrap.js'
       ]
```

And my `test_a.js` looks like:

```
define(['A/B/C'], function(D){ 
  //test case
})
```

But the browser looks for `localhost:9876/base/A/B/C.js` and returns an error because only `localhost:9876/base/src/js/a.js` exists in browser.

My question is, since `src/js/a.js` is loaded already, and I introduce `requirejs` in `karma.conf.js`, why couldn't the module loaded by its id? Did I write the `A/B/C` module in wrong way?

My `require.config` in `test/test-bootstrap.js` is:

```
require.config({
// Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config    file
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9876/base',
paths: {
    'jquery': 'test/lib/jquery-1.12.0.min'
},

// dynamically load all test files
deps: allTestFiles,

// we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

I need to load module by its id because I may change my project structures and I don't want the module path is hard coded into test file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure RequireJS to find your module because you gave it a name that does not correspond to a path that RequireJS can use. In general, it is not advisable to hard code names in modules but if you do have a good reason, then in the part of `test/test-bootstrap.js` that calls `require.config`, you should have a `paths` like this:

```
paths: {
    'A/B/C': 'src/js/a',
    // and whatever else you'd need...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I have `test/test-bootstrap.js` whose function is as same as your `test-main.js`. But in my opinion, if I give a module an id, I can directly use it without configuring path for it. Am I wrong?

Comment: In the case you are presenting, there is no way for RequireJS to find your module without specifying it in the configuration.

Comment: Yes, after I add the path, it works. I think I should read more about `requirejs`.